# Set position of TabTip keyboard c# is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, dllimport

I am trying to reposition the TabTib keyboard without success the SetWindowPos function returns "True" but the keyboard is not moving.
I am using C# on windows 7.

`
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,
    int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string ClassName, string WindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
        public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
        public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
        public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
    }

    Rectangle KeyboardRect;
    IntPtr TabTipHandle;

   IntPtr GetWindowHandle()
    {
        return FindWindow("IPTip_Main_Window",null);
    }

   bool MoveKeyBoard(IntPtr hWnd, int ToX, int ToY)
    {
       return SetWindowPos(hWnd, this.Handle, ToX, ToY, KeyboardRect.Width, KeyaboardRect.Height, 0x0045);
    }
    void StartKeyboard()
    {
        Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe");
        TabTipHandle = GetWindowHandle();
        KeyboardRect = GetKeyboardRect(TabTipHandle);
        textBox1.Text = KeyaboardRect.Top.ToString() + ", " + KeyboardRect .Left.ToString()      + ", " + KeyboardRect .Width.ToString() + ", " + KeyboardRect .Height.ToString();

        MoveKeyBoard(TabTipHandle, 100, 100);
        KeyboardRect = GetKeyboardRect(TabTipHandle);
        textBox2.Text = KeyaboardRect.Top.ToString() + ", " + KeyboardRect .Left.ToString()      + ", " + KeyboardRect .Width.ToString() + ", " + KeyboardRect .Height.ToString();
     }
    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      StartKeyboard();
    }
    void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MoveKeyBoard(TabTipHandle, 200, 100);
        KeyboardRect = GetKeyboardRect(TabTipHandle);
        textBox2.Text = KeyboardRect .Top.ToString() + ", " + KeyboardRect .Left.ToString()      + ", " + KeyboardRect .Width.ToString() + ", " + KeyboardRect .Height.ToString();

    }
```

`

Comment: Are you sure the handle is the correct one? You can use `spyxx.exe` program to ensure that the handle returned by `FindWindow` is the correct one

Comment: The handle is OK I used spy++ to check it.
I get the same handle by using  "Process.GetProcessesByName("TabTip");"

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you put a small delay just after creating the process like so:

```
 Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe");
 await Task.Delay(150); // Just a tiny delay before continuing
 ...
 MoveKeyBoard(TabTipHandle, 100, 100);
 ...
```

However now I am facing the curious problem that the keyboard will not be exactly positioned where I want it to be by using `SetWindowPos`. The window seems to wobble around the point until it stays fixed after several calls to `SetWindowPos`. Very strange, if you would ask me. In lack of any documentation I searched the registry, because I noted that TabTip.exe will start at the exact same position where it was shutdown. So I found these two DWORD registry values:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\OptimizedKeyboardRelativeXPositionOnScreen
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\OptimizedKeyboardRelativeYPositionOnScreen
```

I experimented with those values and it seems that setting both to `50000` before starting the process will position the keyboard's top left corner to the center of the screen. Setting both to `0` will position it exactly in the top left corner and `100000` for both means top right corner accordingly.